# Debian nvidia-cuda-* packages conflict with gcc-6

Tags: debian, nvidia, gcc

I'm trying to compile a CUDA program on a Google Cloud VM running Debian Stretch. CUDA does not seem to officially supported on Debian but I was able to to install `nvcc` by installing the `nvidia-cuda-dev` and `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` packages.

My problem is that this installs CUDA 8.0 which requires gcc-5. gcc-5 in turn is not available via apt.

Since I will have to repeat this installation process on several other virtual machines I'd like to avoid complicated workarounds here. What is the easiest way to obtain compatible versions of CUDA and gcc? Is seems very strange to me that the `nvidia-cuda-*` packages are clearly unusable with the only available gcc version, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does your Debian Stretch Google Cloud VM even have a CUDA-enabled GPU?

Comment: Yes. I have somewhat circumvented the problem now by installing `gcc-5` inside an anaconda environment.